# Show the app bar on tap

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I need to show/hide the application bar when the user taps (or clicks) anywhere on the page. The page is just a `FlipView` with images. I tried using the `Page.Tapped` event and it fires on tap and click right as I want. The problem is that it also fires when I click on the `FlipView` prev/next controls. This is the handler of the event:

```
private void PageTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.TopAppBar.IsOpen = !this.TopAppBar.IsOpen;
}
```

I don't actually need to handle the event for hiding the app bar, because it has `IsSticky="True"`. Any suggestions how to fix this?

**UPDATE**: The best example of the desired behavior is the Photos app.

**UPDATE 2**: The workaround that I found is to check the `TappedRoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource` object and if that's one of the `Flipview` arrows, I don't change the app bars state. The code is something like this:

```
private void PageTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool changeAppBarState = true;
    var sourceBorder = e.OriginalSource as Border;

    if (sourceBorder != null)
    {
        var element = sourceBorder.Child as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && element.Name == "Arrow")
        {
            changeAppBarState = false;
        }
    }

    if (changeAppBarState)
    {
        this.TopAppBar.IsOpen = !this.TopAppBar.IsOpen;
        this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen = !this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen;
    }
}
```

I still think there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the SelectionChanged event of the flip-view and you can mange the behavior of the app-bar in that.

This will work same as the Photos app

`<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <FlipView Margin="0,80,0,80" SelectionChanged="FlipView_SelectionChanged">
            <Image Source="Assets/Logo.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="150"/>
            <Image Source="Assets/SplashScreen.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Image Source="Assets/SmallLogo.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </FlipView>
    </Grid>`

```
private void FlipView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen = false;
        this.TopAppBar.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

Comment: It's not working, I've already tried this, but the `SelectionChanged`event is fired before the `Page.Tapped`